# How to detect when browser height is less than device height CSS

Tags: css

I have a page where the CSS of an element needs to be modified for devices like the Nexus 5X (which has the 'Android nav bars' at the top and bottom - these push the elements on the page around)

Currently I use this jQuery to detect and adjust this. But is there a way to do this by CSS media queries instead?

Code below:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                        is_mobile = true;
                    }
if ($( window ).height()<window.screen.height && is_mobile==true) {
            $('#my_element').css("height","46vh");
        }
```

So in CSS I was thinking something like comparing height < device-height (and another condition to check for mobile which is simple), but apparently device-height is deprecated (and also I don't think I can do such a comparison directly between the 2 heights anyway)?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that in pure CSS, but you could make the JS solution cleaner by setting a class on the body element instead of setting the style directly.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use `media query`:

```
@media all and (min-height: yourValue ) {
  selector {
    //Code Css
  }
}
```

> read more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: thanks but how do i set a single media query condition that is based both on the device height, and the browser height?

Comment: you have to give specific height min-height for mobile devices and create a class for the same https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/